# Why is this Dm Commands Not Working for Some id ? Discord js

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

```
    const devs = [
        'user1ID',
        'user2ID',
        'user3ID',
        'user4ID'
    ]

    if (devs.includes(message.author.id)) {
        const target = client.users.cache.get(args[0]);

        let payload = message.content.slice(8)

        if (!target) return message.channel.send("User not found");

        client.users.cache.get(target.id).send(payload)
        message.channel.send("DM has been Sent :tick:")
        .catch(() => message.lineReply("User has DMs closed or has no mutual servers with the bot"));
    }
    else {
        message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command")
    }
```

It Says User Not found for Some ids and other it sent dm successfully and also when it sent it send the id also. Please help me.

Comment: Make sure you have `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` enabled and `args[0]` is a valid ID.

Comment: why args o is invalid ?